# Python: groupby multiple columns and generate count column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

input dataframe

```
row     name    Min
11      AA      0.3
11      AA      0.2
11      BB      0.3
11      CC      0.2
12      AS      0.3
12      BE      0.3
12      BE      0.4
```

need to generate new column '`count`' which holds info on number of times each row-name combo occurs.

**Expected Output**

```
row     name    Min     Count
11      AA      0.3         2
11      AA      0.2         2
11      BB      0.3         1
11      CC      0.2         1
12      AS      0.3         1
12      BE      0.3         2
12      BE      0.4         2
```

Comment: Please Justify the count values ! for the first the count values is 2 and in your input AA and 0.3 has only be repeated once !

Comment: have to consider the combo row and name. Not Min.

Comment: Check out the answer hope it helps !

Comment: The marked answer is usually more time consuming since it performs `merge` operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

merge in the counts?

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['row', 'name']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Count'}), on=['row','name'])

    row name    Min Count
0   11  AA  0.3 2
1   11  AA  0.2 2
2   11  BB  0.3 1
3   11  CC  0.2 1
4   12  AS  0.3 1
5   12  BE  0.3 2
6   12  BE  0.4 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to generate the column `count` using `transform`

```py
df['count'] = df.groupby(['row', 'name'])["Min"].transform("count")

    row name    Min count
0   11  AA     0.3  2
1   11  AA     0.2  2
2   11  BB     0.3  1
3   11  CC     0.2  1
4   12  AS     0.3  1
5   12  BE     0.3  2
6   12  BE     0.4  2
```